# Why I have an authorization error in my DB2?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Have a problem. I can't finish my course of SQL on coursera because DB2 sends me:

[jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.26.14] Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000

Other products like Watson works fine. Support can't help me because of my account: to solve my ticket they want me to update account.

Comment: That error indicates that your credentials are wrong - or that the product behind has trouble processing your credentials. Add details on what Db2 you are using. If you are on a Lite account with the free Db2, check the product FAQ for troubleshooting.